# Use Spring Beans In Micronaut Applications

Tags: java, spring, micronaut

I have been looking for something like this.

Having this micronaut app code

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cassandra.CassandraAutoConfiguration.class,
        org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAutoConfiguration.class,
        org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration.class,
        org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = HelloController.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.setProperty("akka.config", "/Users/nb38tv/workspace/hello-micronaut/src/main/resources/config/");
        System.setProperty("akka.config.file", "application.conf");
        ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext = ReactiveConnectorBootable.loadReactiveConnector();

        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new MicronautApplicationContext();
        context.setParent(springContext);
        context.start();

        Micronaut.run(Application.class);

    }

}
```

How can I merge an ApplicationContext of Spring with the one of Micronaut.

I need it since I have a library that use ApplicationContext of Spring to inject some beans.

Then in my controller I need to use it.

```
@Controller("/hello")
public class HelloController {

    @Inject
    private ReactorConnectorManager<RequestInfoDTO, String> reactorConnectorRestManagerExecutor;

    @Get(produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String index() {
        if(reactorConnectorRestManagerExecutor == null){
            return "boooo";
        }
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Where `ReactorConnectorManager` is a bean loaded in `Spring context`

Regards

Comment: Do you want do something with your beans only when application is starting or you want use beans from your Micronaut context?

Comment: I want to inject Spring bean in Micronaut application, I will update my question

Comment: I tried this code and create a simple app and it seems to working. Can you check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [this](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-spring/latest/guide/index.html) there is an example how to integrate [Micronaut with Spring](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-spring/blob/master/examples/greeting-service/src/main/java/greeting/example/Application.java)

I have created a simple application base on [this](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-spring/blob/master/examples/greeting-service/src/main/java/greeting/example/Application.java), code above.
And for example on `http://localhost:8080/hello/World` it returns: `Hello World with Test : World and Test : World`. So it looks like `Controller` uses `Bean`.

```java
package greeting.example;

import io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import java.util.function.Function;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Micronaut.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    Function<String, String> stringService(){
        return (value) -> "Test : "+ value;
    }
}
```

And

```java
package greeting.example;

import io.micronaut.http.MediaType;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;
import io.reactivex.Single;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.function.Function;

@Controller("/")
public class HelloController {

    @Inject
    Function<String, String> stringService;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Get(uri = "/hello/{name}", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Single<String> hello(String name) {
        Function<String, String> service =  applicationContext.getBean(Function.class);
        return Single.just("Hello " + name + " with " + stringService.apply(name)
                + " and " + service.apply(name));
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

A hack that allows to get access to `ConfigurableApplicationContext context`. In `Application` create something like singleton or in my example static field that hold your `context`:

```java
static ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;

...

ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext = ReactiveConnectorBootable.loadReactiveConnector();
```

And then in your `HelloController`:

```java
@Get(produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String index() {
    ReactorConnectorManager<RequestInfoDTO, String> reactorConnectorRestManagerExecutor =
            Application.springContext.getBean(ReactorConnectorManager<RequestInfoDTO, String>.class);
    if(reactorConnectorRestManagerExecutor  == null){
        return "boooo";
    }
    return "Hello World";
}
```

Comment: I follow that, unfortunately it does not work. Work 100% micronaut or 100% Spring boot, but you cannot mix both features together.

Comment: But that example is not my case. Try to obtain an ApplicationContext from Spring with some beans already loaded, and try to inject those beans in Micronaut

Comment: Thanks, but I don't quite understand why you can not obtain beans. I change the example to use also ApplicationContext. @paul

Comment: @paul "Work 100% micronaut or 100% Spring boot, but you cannot mix both features together." - That is not true.  You can definitely mix them together.  We have done that in Grails 4 and have libraries to help do that completely independent of Grails. There is more than 1 option.  1 is you could use Micronaut as the parent context.  Another option is you can use https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-spring which allows you to do things like expose Micronaut beans to a Spring app. There are numerous ways to go about it, definitely not the case that you can't use them together.

Comment: I just use this code as it can be found here https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-spring/tree/master/examples/greeting-service but I was not able to make it works. Could you provide a doc/code trying to do something similar as I paste in my example. Basically having a ApplicationContext from Spring, reuse the beans loaded by Spring into Micronaut context. I cannot control how the library load the beans using Spring, since is an external library that use ioc of Spring

Comment: @paul could you explain the meaning of `MicronautApplicationContext` and `ReactiveConnectorBootable.loadReactiveConnector()`

Comment: ReactiveConnectorBootable is a library that load some beans using spring. The MicronautApplicationContext I’d something that I saw in Micronaut-spring documentation to use it for setParent with another context. But in my example it does not work

Comment: Maybe in first try try to write simple application with spring boot and this library. If it works then replace spring boot to micronaut. I don't know how to simulate this library (xml file with beans?). @paul

Comment: To simulate, just create an AaplicationContext of Spring loading some foo bean, and then try to use that bean in the Micronaut app

Comment: And yeah I have working Micronaut with Spring, but still don’t know how to merge an existed ApplicationContext already. That’s the main question

Comment: "And yeah I have working Micronaut with Spring," - Great.  I thought you were saying that they couldn't be mixed.  I think I misunderstood.

Comment: But still don’t know how to get an already existed ApplicationContext and merge into Micronaut context and being able to inject some of those beans

Comment: @paul I added an idea for hack how to get access to yours beans

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but that hack is not really useful when you want to inject beans with generic types. your code getBean(ReactorConnectorManager<RequestInfoDTO, String>.class); it cannot compile. Thanks again for all the effort

Comment: But you gave me a good idea with the static. Now using the static to get the bean and using @Factory I can make a proxy to recreate the beans in Micronaut. Thanks man, the inspiration was all yours!. If nobody suggest a more elegant solution I will give you tomorrow the correct answer