# How to use an SDK written using Spring in Micronaut

Tags: java, spring-boot, micronaut

I have an existing SDK written using the Spring Framework. I want to use it in a new Micronaut Application. Have tried the method suggested in [micronaut-spring](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-spring/latest/guide/), but run into `No existing bean found for bean key: com.org.sdk-name.TestService`.

1. Do I need to make any changes to the SDK itself for making it compatible with Micronaut ? (As of now, I have only made changes in the Micronaut application to integrate the SDK)
2. How do i tell the Micronaut Application to look for beans present in the external SDK ? (Perhaps by using the micronaut equivalent of `@ComponentScan`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Spring Beans In Micronaut Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58476782/use-spring-beans-in-micronaut-applications)

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to make any changes to the SDK itself for making it
> compatible with Micronaut ?

Without knowing what your software development kit does, it would be impossible to answer that in a reliable way.

> How do i tell the Micronaut Application to look for beans present in
> the external SDK ?

Micronaut doesn't have the notion of looking for beans in an SDK.  For whatever that means, you would have to build that support yourself.

If the SDK is really just a library or collection of libraries then the way that Micronaut consumes dependencies provided in those library(ies) is to simply add a dependency a dependency on the library in your build file.

**UPDATE:**

> How do i tell the Micronaut Application to look for beans present in
> the external SDK ?

Add the libraries provided by the external SDK to your runtime classpath.

Comment: Here https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-spring/blob/master/examples/greeting-service/src/main/java/greeting/example/Application.java

Comment: @SusanMustafa I don't think I understand the issue.  I am sorry that I cannot help.  Best of luck.

Comment: No worries.  My fault really.  I misunderstood the example in the documentation :)

Comment: Thanks @JeffScottBrown, will try it out.

Comment: "will try it out" - @mayankjhamtani Awesome.  It definitely works.  The runtime classpath is how the classloader will discover the relevant components.

Comment: "Have tried the method suggested in micronaut-spring, but run into No existing bean found for bean key: com.org.sdk-name.TestService." - Is `TestService` in a Spring module that is being compiled with `micronaut-spring` configured as a compile time annotation processor?